# Creating a playlist in laravel - associating many foreign keys with one record?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm new to laravel and I have never modeled a playlist type of entity before, so I'm looking for best practices and guidance.

I have two models **song** and **playlist**.

Playlists have many songs. I would like the user to be able to fill out a single form to create/edit a playlist and select as many songs as they like.

What's the best way to do this? Is there a way to store an array of ids as foreign keys to the songs table? Or should this always write out many rows to a mapping table?

Does laravel or eloquent have a way to assist in the CRUD for this kind of a model? What is best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Laravel supports M:N relationships. In my opinion, the simplest way to do what you want is by creating a `playlist_song` table and store all the relationships between `song` and `playlist`.

You can use the `attach`, `detach` and `sync` methods to control the foreign relationships. To make it easier to understand, I made an example:

```
class Song extends \Eloquent {
    public function playlists() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Model\Playlist', 'playlist_song');
    }
}

class Playlist extends \Eloquent {
    public function songs() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Model\Songs', 'playlist_song');
    }
}
```

In your controller, you could use something like this to synchronize all the songs contained in a playlist:

```
$playlist->songs()->sync(array(1, 2, 3)); // The numbers are the ids
```

For a complete documentation about Laravel Eloquent, please check http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you Pedro! I have that set up as a proof of concept and working nicely. However, now I need to figure out a nice way to create the form element to add the songs! Right now I just type the ids into a text field. Thank you!